# User's relationship collection emptied afted user was updated

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactive-programming, angular-meteor

I have two collections: `users` and `tradeOffers`. Each `user` has a unique `steamid` field. Each `tradeOffer` has field `recipient.steamid`. On server I publish `tradeOffers` collection like this:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

import { TradeOffers } from './collection';

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish("tradeOffers", function () {
        let user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId });

        return TradeOffers.find({
            'recipient.steamid': user.services.steam.steamid
        });
    });
}
```

On client side I subscribe to this collection and display current user's trade offers. Everything works fine until I update the user. Whenever current user is updated, data disappears from the view. After page reload I can see trade offers again. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add the rest of your related codes please